# Can't shutdown or Reboot system Ubuntu 14.04LTS (HP X360)

Tags: intel-graphics, hp, intel, tablet

just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bits, everything went out of the box but the system won't power off the Tablet-PC if i press ESC while the OS turns OFF i can see that it gets stuck with "*Will now Halt"

Please help me since most popular fixes did not worked

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar laptop and haven't had this trouble thru a couple Linux installs. You should look into making sure everything is updated and installed via the usual:

```
sudo update && sudo upgrade
```

You can also add in `sudo dist-upgrade` if apt-get keeps a few system packages back.

Short term I would try this command to see if you can shutdown via terminal.:

```
sudo poweroff
```

as `sudo Shutdown` has never worked for me.

For a long term fix we need more information on the Error you get, and laptop specs possibly using `lshw`

Comment: Fixed by installing Debian using -nonfree- CD btw i want to see desktop shortcuts in Gnome(debian 8)?